# Prove or refute that $g \circ f$ with $dom(g \circ f) = A...$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Here is my question from an assignment:

> Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: \text{ran}(f) \to C$ be functions. We define the composition of $f$ and $g$ as the relation $g \circ f$ from $A$ to $C$ such that $(x,y)\in g \circ f \iff g(f(x)) = y$. Prove or refute $g \circ f$ is a function with $\text{dom}(g \circ f) = A$.

I have no idea how to do this. Also, I have only a slight understanding of the concept the question is asking about. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Where is your conceptual difficulty with the question?

Comment: $\text{dom}(gf)=\{x|x \in \text{dom} f=A, f(x)\in \text{dom} g=rank f\}= A$

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm gonna proof that $dom(g \circ f)= dom(f) =A$, for a theorem, if $$ran(f) \subseteq dom(g) \implies dom(g \circ f)=dom(f)$$. 
For hypothesis $dom(g)=ran(f)$ then $dom(g \circ f)=dom(f)$. By the definition of function $dom(f)=A$. Now, i'm gonna proof $(x,z_1) \in g \circ f \land (x,z_2) \in g \circ f \implies z_1=z_2$. Suppose  $(x,z_1) \in g \circ f \land (x,z_2) \in g \circ f$ by the definition of composition 
$$(( \exists y_1)(x,y_1)\in f \land (y_1,z_1) \in g) \land (( \exists y_2)(x,y_2)\in f \land (y_2,z_2) \in g) \\
( \exists y_1)(\exists y_2)(x,y_1) \in f \land (x,y_2) \in f \land (y_1,z_1) \in g \land (y_2,z_2) \in g$$
As $f$ is a function, then $y_1=y_2$
$$(\exists y_1)(x,y_1) \in f \land (y_1,z_1) \in g \land (y_1,z_2) \in g$$
Similarly, as $g$ is function then $z_1=z_2$. So $g \circ f$ is a function $\blacksquare$